# How do I set a field to equal another field in another class

Tags: java, pointers

I have the following: 
**Class 1:**

```
public class SellProduct
{
    private int productCost;
    public SellProduct(int productCost)
    {
     this.productCost = productCost;   
    }

    public int getProductCost()
    {
        return productCost;
    }
}
```

This class will set how much a product costs.
**Class 2:**

```
public class SalesOfTheYear
{
    private int totalIncome;
    SellProduct sellProduct;

    public SalesOfTheYear()
    {
     totalIncome = 0;
    }

    public void cashOut()
    {
       totalIncome = sellProduct.getProductCost() + totalIncome;
    }

    public int getSalesOfTheYear()
    {
         return totalIncome;
    }
}
```

Now what I want is that class two to take how much the products cost and then set it to the totalIncome field. And of course to keep it's value at the same time and not replace it with a new totalIncome value.
However, every time I run cashout it sends a java.lang.NullPointerException. Does this mean I have to create an object of class sellPoduct?
And if do I would have to supply it with a parameter does that mean that whatever I supply it with a parameter so will it always be the productCost?

Comment: Creating one account to ask the same question wasn't enough? ([set a field equal to another field from another class](//stackoverflow.com/q/40751330))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to pass product cost to `cashOut()` method and add it into `totalIncome` rather than storing reference of `SellProduct` itself. It will look like this:

```
public void cashOut(int cost){
    totalIncome += cost;
}
```

Also, we don't need default constructor in `SalesOfTheYear` class as `int` literals are assigned default values (0 in this case) when object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Java whenever you have your own classes like SellProduct you will have to initialise it with:

```
SellProduct sellProduct = new SellProduct(xxx);
```

with xxx being an integer in your case

If you give it the number 20 then your totalIncome will increase with 20 every time you run cashOut()

Comment: Can you have this? SellProduct sellProduct = new SellProduct(totalIncome);

Comment: If you want totalincome and product cost to be the same **object** then you have to use "Integer" instead of "int"

Answer (score 0):

To update the `totalIncome` field in a `SalesOfTheYear` instance, you need to transmit all required SellProduct instances to `SalesOfTheYear` .
Either, you have all the instances and you provide them in one time, either you may provide instance by instance.

```
 public class SalesOfTheYear
    {
    private int totalIncome;
    SellProduct sellProduct;
    public SalesOfTheYear()
    {
     totalIncome = 0;
    }

     public void cashOut(SellProduct sellProduct)
    {
       totalIncome = sellProduct.getProductCost() + totalIncome;
    }

    public void cashOut(List<SellProduct> sellProducts)
    {
       for (SellProduct product : sellProducts){
          cashOut(product);
        }
    }

    public int getSalesOfTheYear()
    {
       return totalIncome;
    }
  }
```

How to use :

```
SalesOfTheYear salesOfTheYear = new SalesOfTheYear();
salesOfTheYear.cashOut(new SellProduct(500));
salesOfTheYear.cashOut(new SellProduct(100));
int totalSale = salesOfTheYear.getSalesOfTheYear();
```